# Cannot order by date in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Here's a request that grabs all those fight events with the number of confirmed fights more than 4, it also does some specific time selection but it does not matter (it looks weird cos this request is executed by the ORM I'm using so it just puts in some boolean values where they are supposed to be).

```
SELECT
    "fightEventId"
FROM location_time_slot AS lts
WHERE "fightId" IN (
    SELECT
        f.id
    FROM fights AS f
    WHERE f.status = 'CONFIRMED'
) AND "fightEventId" IN (
    SELECT
        fe.id
    FROM fight_events AS fe
    WHERE true AND (
        NOW() at time zone 'utc' >= fe.from AND NOW() at time zone 'utc' <= fe.to
    ) OR true AND NOW() at time zone 'utc' <= fe.to
      OR false AND NOW() at time zone 'utc' > fe.to
)
GROUP BY "fightEventId"
HAVING 
    COUNT("fightId") > 4
LIMIT 1
OFFSET 0;
```

I would also like to sort (order) this output by the parameter called "from_date" that is present in the `location_time_slot` table.

If I add it like this:

```
SELECT
    "fightEventId"
FROM location_time_slot AS lts
WHERE "fightId" IN (
    SELECT
        f.id
    FROM fights AS f
    WHERE f.status = 'CONFIRMED'
) AND "fightEventId" IN (
    SELECT
        fe.id
    FROM fight_events AS fe
    WHERE true AND (
        NOW() at time zone 'utc' >= fe.from AND NOW() at time zone 'utc' <= fe.to
    ) OR true AND NOW() at time zone 'utc' <= fe.to
      OR false AND NOW() at time zone 'utc' > fe.to
)
GROUP BY "fightEventId", from_date 
HAVING 
    COUNT("fightId") > 4
ORDER BY from_date DESC 
LIMIT 1
OFFSET 0;
```

The query executes but it returns nothing but one id is expected to be returned.

Seems like I'm grouping something the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

If I was going to guess, I would say that once you add the grouping by `from_date`, then you don't have any groups that meet your `count() > 4` criteria.

to test this, select all your columns:

```
select
    "fightEventId"
, from_date
, count("fightEventId")
from ....
```

and then remove your `HAVING` clause to see what results you get before the `HAVING` clause is applied.